# How to call a popup window in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have webform1,webform2. I have a submit button in webform1.When the submit is  clicked, it has to perform some function then based on the result i have to show different data (let say accept/decline images) in the webform2(POPUP). When this popup is displayed user should not be allowed to make any changes to webform1.

Let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you asking for a "modal" popup?

You should try with ShowModalDialog method.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following code in the pageLoad method:

```
YourButtonID.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('WebForm2.aspx',null,'left=400, top=100, height=350, width= 580, status=no, resizable= no, scrollbars= yes, toolbar= no,location= no, menubar= no');");
```

EDIT: Place the code in the Button_Clicked event handler instead in pageLoad...works in both ways, but it is better solution...

Comment: i tried this but the code is getting executed but not navigating to the webform2.

Comment: it works in all my projects. Check again if you are missing something

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try AJAX Modal Popup... [Click Here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) for the sample...

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this in my web application I used raw HTML+CSS+Javascript.

Basically what you need is a top level div added to body with 100% size. Then another div with margin:auto, sized the way you want.. You could make that earlier div transparent or semi transparent using CSS.

This will only work on the good browsers ;)